# Components in components aren't rendered server-side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I'm new to react and javascript and have received the task to change an existing application from client-side rendering to server-side rendering. I've followed this repository's structure (https://github.com/ayroblu/ssr-cra-v2.1) and was able to render the components server-side. The problem is that there are some components included inside other components, which are empty when I check the page's source.

I have a component which is included in the root and is successfully rendered, but inside it I include other routes, which are not getting rendered server-side:

```
<div className="layout-content">
  <Switch location={location}> 
    {routes.map(route => ( <Route key={route.name} path={route.path} component={route.component} exact/> ))} 
  </Switch>
</div>
```

And in this case, the source page contains an empty div.
I would appreciate any help!

Regards,
Andrew

Comment: where do the Switch and Route components come from?